# Questdb write permissions issues

Tags: questdb

I am trying to run query

```
BACKUP DATABASE;
```

I'm getting response `Write permission denied`
At the moment it's not clear what prevents write to disk. I'm running QuestDB database are root process.

Answer (score 1):

This error means instance is running in read-only mode .
You can change it by adding/editing the following line in conf/server.conf :

> http.security.readonly=false

and restarting the instance.